# Considering scale factors in the arc length integral

Tags: calculus

Writing a high school math assignment recently i came across this issue. I had to find the arc length of a function of my own making, lets call it f(x). I defined a scale of 10x on the x axis and 50x on the y axis. But i cant figure out how to apply this to the arc length integral:

[Intergal for arc length of f(x) without considering scale factor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kcT6.png)

Could anyone explain how this can be done? I don't fully understand the arc length integral, it wasn't the point of the assignment

Comment: Do you mean you want to understand how to compute an arc length integral? If so, there are many notes/examples online, e.g. https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/arclength.aspx

Comment: No. The thing i'm getting at is something more like this [link](https://imgur.com/a/IJ8P4JH) except integrated to find an 'exact value'. I know this can be done using the arc length integral but im not sure how to do it with this scale in mind

Comment: So just to be sure, you have a function, but the point $(1,1)$ on that function actually corresponds with $(10,50)$?

Comment: Correct. like multiplying a vector by a scaling matirx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using differentials, we know differential in arc length is typically

$$ds=\sqrt{(dx)^2+(dy)^2}.$$

In your setup, we have

$$ds=\sqrt{(10dx)^2+(50dy)^2}=\sqrt{100+2500\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2}dx.$$

Thus, you must compute

$$\int_a^b \sqrt{100+2500\left(f'(x)\right)^2}dx.$$

Comment: Thanks, this really helps. I've never seen this method where isolated dx and dy are used. Does it have an explicit name?

Comment: They are called differentials, and they offer an easy heuristic way to obtain the arc length integral (e.g. see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integrating))